# How to prevent CSS declaration dropped errors cross browser?

Tags: css, cross-browser

Hi I would like to know how to easily prevent dropped errors from appearing from debugging software such as webdeveloper plugin in Firefox. I get errors such as:

Warning: Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.

Warning: Error in parsing value for 'font'.  Declaration dropped.

I understand I get these errors because Firefox does not support these CSS properties, but how do I drop them before hand so Firefox does not attempt to read them in the first place? I know I can create a separate style sheet for every browser but that is a inconvenience. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Shouldn't creating a stylesheet for the MS browsers only with the offending properties and one for all browsers be enough in this case?

Comment: if you only need to support IE >8, you could use `-ms-filter` and put the value in quotes (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) so that it confirms to CSS standards.

Comment: filter is not a CSS property and is proprietary to IE alone. Firefox handles 'font' just fine. Firefox simply ignores the filter property as any modern browser would.

Comment: This is not an IE-only issue.  iOS workarounds cause this in Firefox too--try getskeleton.com for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I'd *always* put or import IE-specific styles inside a [conditonal comment](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html);
2. as standard CSS FF should be fine with '[font](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_font_font.asp)', so just check your syntax e.g. `font: bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;` values separated by spaces, multi-word font names in quotes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IE-specific declaration (like `filter`), put it in an IE-specific stylesheet. It is simple and easy, and I don't really understand why it would be an incovenience (the inconvenience is IE itself).

Hiding an error does not mean the error is solved (and actually if FF shows an error in `font` it should be taken care of).